# Why can't I make a group repeat in regex Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex I want to construct for validating the UNC syntax, which is:

\\server\shared\folder\path

I don't care about the server or folder characters, I exclusively want to validate the \thing1\thing2maybe3 syntax, the server and folder names will be validated separately.

This is what I have so far:

```
(^\\\\\w+)(\\{1}\w+)+(.+(?<!\\)$)
```

These are my tests:

1. MATCH - \\server\multiple\folders\example\path
2. FAIL - \\server\\multiple\folders\example\path
3. SHOULD FAIL - \\server\multiple\\folders\example\path
4. FAIL - \\server\multiplefolders\example\path\
5. FAIL - \\server
6. FAIL - \\\server\multiple
7. SHOULD MATCH - \\server\m
8. MATCH - \\server\m\w\z

I'm testing here:
https://regex101.com/r/WqF7h7/1

Can anyone help making #3 and #7 fail and match respectively?

#3 has a second double slash after "multiple", this shouldn't be permitted, only at the beginning should there be double slashes. This should fail like #2

#7 has the correct syntax and should be matching like #8

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\\{1,2}\w+(?:\\\w+)+$
```

In Java with the doubled backslashes:

```
String regex = "^\\\\{1,2}\\w+(?:\\\\\\w+)+$";
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\\{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 backslashes
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\\\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times 1 or more word characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FdLEc/1)

Or a bit less strict version matching any char except `\` instead of only word characters:

```
^\\{1,2}[^\\]+(?:\\[^\\]+)+$
```

Comment: Not really doing what it's supposed to, I updated my question with this:
#3 has a second double slash after "multiple", this shouldn't be permitted, only at the beginning should there be double slashes. This should fail like #2. 

#7 has the correct syntax and should be matching like #8

Comment: @RaulMarquez The pattern matches all the examples. See https://regex101.com/r/MCJNSv/1

Comment: I see it now, you're right, I have a bunch of tabs open and might have clicked the wrong one, thanks. I forgot to add this case "sometextbefore\\server" which should fail, a UNC path must start with \\. Can you help with this?

Comment: @RaulMarquez It already fails, see https://regex101.com/r/LGsuZm/1

Comment: Man, I just can't today lol, thanks.